# How to connect to other netty server when a netty server is started?

Tags: netty

I want netty server A to connect netty server B on start up,sounds like proxy,so I tried [netty proxy example](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy),but it just starts netty client in `channelActive`, only a new connection active,the client will be created.
When the server A started, I need to notify server B to do some "register" stuff, how could I do?

Comment: Could you please give a bit more information? The example you linked to does demonstrate how a proxy would work (at a basic level). What do you mean when you say that you want to _"connect to other netty server"_ - are you looking to have two distinct Netty processes running as a server (i.e. in a way which receives data in), but make them 'speak to' each other?

Comment: @TristanPerry see my answer,thank you

Answer (score 0):

@Tristan Perry 
Here is my [code](https://gist.github.com/RTM945/6d0d3b71e585ab226b6d54c7821e4060),it worked,but I don't know if there are some better solution.

Comment: That would work fine - connecting to server B only after the successful startup of server A makes sense, as does the inbound handler which can send the response back to server A.

In terms of 'sharing' data between the two, you might already know but you can do `ctx.channel.attr(..).set()` and `ctx.channel.attr(..).get()` to store data against a channel. This may or may not be helpful, but just mentioning as an FYI.